# How to properly test with mocks Akka actors in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, akka

I'm very new with Akka and I'm trying to write some unit tests in Java. Consider the following actor:

```
public class Worker extends UntypedActor {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {

    if (message instanceof Work) {
      Work work = (Work) message;
      Result result = new Helper().processWork(work);
      getSender().tell(result, getSelf());
    } else {
      unhandled(message);
    }
  }

}
```

What is the proper way to intercept the call `new Helper().processWork(work)`? On a side note, is there any recommended way to achieve dependency injection within Akka actors with Java?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is already properly testable:

- you can test your business logic separately, since you can just instantiate your `Helper` outside of the actor
- once you are sure that the `Helper` does what it is supposed to do, just send some inputs to the actor and observe that the right replies come back

Now if you need to have a “mocked” `Worker` to test some other component, just don’t use a Worker at all, use a `TestProbe` instead. Where you would normally get the `ActorRef` of the Worker, just inject `probe.getRef()`.

So, how to inject that?

I’ll assume that your other component is an Actor (because otherwise you won’t have trouble applying whatever injection technique you normally use). Then there are three basic choices:

1. pass it in as constructor argument
2. send it within a message
3. if the actor creates the ref as its child, pass in the `Props`, possibly in an alternative constructor

The third case is probably what you are looking at (I’m guessing based on the actor class’ name):

```
public class MyParent extends UntypedActor {
  final Props workerProps;

  public MyParent() {
    workerProps = new Props(...);
  }
  public MyParent(Props p) {
    workerProps = p;
  }

  ...
  getContext().actorOf(workerProps, "worker");
}
```

And then you can inject a `TestProbe` like this:

```
final TestProbe probe = new TestProbe(system);
final Props workerMock = new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
  public UntypedActor create() {
    return new UntypedActor() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Object msg) {
        probe.getRef().tell(msg, getSender());
      }
    };
  }
});
final ActorRef parent = system.actorOf(new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
  public UntypedActor create() {
    return new MyParent(workerMock);
  }
}), "parent");
```

Comment: In general, this is a solid approach but it does have a hiccup: in some cases the parent actor may want to supply arguments to the child. In this case, some kind of *Props factory* will have to be supplied (rather than an instance of Props) - just be mindful of the serializability of such factories.